# Localhost windows10 took to loong to respond

Tags: reactjs, localhost, expo

Hi I'm Surya I'm facing this localhost took to long to respond in my windows computer I thought the problem was with react and again it happened in the expo so it is a problem in my computer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3crJv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87JJf.png)

it also compiled successfully I tried disabling my firewall and my antivirus(Quick Heal) and my antivirus is not yet expired everything is good but I do no what is the problem please help me with this problem .

Answer (score 0):

The issue is mostly caused by firewall or antivirus. Re assure that you have disabled antivirus software and firewall. Also, check the network connection and ensure that you are not connected to proxy.
After performing all these, try restarting the system.

Comment: I tried all that I do no what's the problem

Comment: Try hosting at diffrent port by creating a .env file at your project root and specify port number there .  Like:

PORT=3005

Comment: I tried still same I think I need to do some changes to my firewall and antivirus

Comment: I finally solved it the problem was with my antivirus I added localhost to be allowed in my quick heal antivirus now everything is good

Comment: Again the problem started this weird I do no why I ran Windows troubleshooter it gave me this error The remote device won't accept the connection localhost

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it the problem was with my antivirus I added localhost to be allowed in my quick heal antivirus now everything is good.

Answer (score 0):

Again the problem started this weird I do no why I ran Windows troubleshooter it gave me this error

```
the remote device won't accept the connection localhost
```